# "Random" object from array that doesn't repeat until all used - with local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I would like to use local storage to make this "random" selection... random, but only based on the remaining objects in the array.

So, if 3 get chosen --- then the randomizer would count that out in the next selection and so on, THEN - when all 4 objects has been used, reset and repeat the whole process. I haven't used local storage that much yet - so I'm looking for some advice on the most elegant way to do this.

```
var sceneChoices = [
    skylineOne = {
        skyline: '01',
        ID: '9YwX81KAqdk'
    },
    skylineTwo = {
        skyline: '02',
        ID: 'bqJwMYzsmHU'
    },
    skylineThree = {
        skyline: '03',
        ID: 'DwNTvj61VQw'
    },
    skylineFour = {
        skyline: '04',
        ID: '2cg-Uc556-Q'
    }
];

if ( typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined' ) { // local storage style

    var randomSunset = sceneChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * sceneChoices.length)];

} else { // regular style

    var randomSunset = sceneChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * sceneChoices.length)];

}

var sunsetName = randomSunset.skyline;
var youTubeId   = randomSunset.ID;
```

( wrote that out pretty quickly... and it was incorrect - as noted below )

I think I really wanted an array like this...

```
var sunsetChoices = [
    {
        ID: '01',
        videoKey: '9YwX81KAqdk'
    },
    {
        ID: '02',
        videoKey: 'bqJwMYzsmHU'
    },
    {
        ID: '03',
        videoKey: 'DwNTvj61VQw'
    },
    {
        ID: '04',
        videoKey: '2cg-Uc556-Q'
    }
];
```

Comment: Your sceneChoices code is not legal Javascript.  Presumably you mean to use `:` instead of `=`.

Comment: And meant for `sceneChoices` to be an object with keys rather than an array.

Comment: Oh --- yeah, I wrote that up in SO quick style ---

Comment: You can shuffle the array and pop, repeat until done.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the remaining choice keys in localStorage and each time you load the page, you select a random item from the remaining choices and then update the remaining choices.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rr75868q/.  Each time you run the jsFiddle, it will display a different sceneChoice item until it has displayed them all, then it will start over again.

```
var sceneChoices = {
    skylineOne: {
        skyline: '01',
        ID: '9YwX81KAqdk'
    },
    skylineTwo: {
        skyline: '02',
        ID: 'bqJwMYzsmHU'
    },
    skylineThree: {
        skyline: '03',
        ID: 'DwNTvj61VQw'
    },
    skylineFour: {
        skyline: '04',
        ID: '2cg-Uc556-Q'
    }
};


// select a random object that has not been used
var items = localStorage.getItem('remainingKeys');
if (items) {
    try {
        items = JSON.parse(items);
    } catch(e) {
        // no nothing, items will still be falsey
        // so it will get initialized in the next code block
    }
}
if (!items || !items.length) {
    // nothing stored, so initialize with all keys
    items = Object.keys(sceneChoices);
}
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
var randomObj = sceneChoices[items[index]];

// now remove the selected item from the items array of keys 
// and then store back to localStorage
items.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem('remainingKeys', JSON.stringify(items));
```

Note: I had to fix the declaration of `sceneChoices` which was not legal Javascript the way you had it.